# Fade out html5 video object after play

Tags: jquery, html, video, html5-video

I have a landing page and all I want to do is fade out the  object after it finishes playing to reveal the background underneath. Fading out either the `<video>` or the `<div>` tags using jQuery or any other method is fine.

```
<div id="video">
<video width="100%" height="auto" autoplay="autoplay">
  <source src="monarch.mp4" type='video/mp4; codecs="avc1.42E01E, mp4a.40.2"'>
  <source src="monarch.ogv" type='video/ogg; codecs="theora, vorbis"'>
</video>
</div>
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try the following:

```
$('#video video').bind('ended', function(){
   $(this).parent().fadeOut()
})
```

Comment: Great, thank you.
This also works using animate to keep the block element intact:

 $('#video video').bind('ended', function(){
     $(this).parent().animate({ opacity: 0 }, 3000);
 })

Comment: Nice and simple!